# Send http_referer from response.redirect page to external website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have links on my asp.net **https** site and want the referrer to show in the web stats for the sites I'm sending visitors to. Since I can't send http_referer info from my https to external http sites, I tried to setup a pass-through page on my site that wasn't secure, then response.redirect from there to the link destination.

> mysite(https) > anotherpage(http) response.redirect > externalsite(http)

But it doesn't send the referrer info from the response.redirect page. It just keeps trying to use the original page that the link was clicked on as the http_referer, which is null due to https.

Is it possible to accomplish this somehow? It seems like it must be, because when I click on a link in facebook (https), it redirects to a different page first, then my analytics show facebook as the referrer (even in Firefox).

Also, I have implemented the meta tag option `<meta name="referrer" content="origin">`, which works for a few browsers, but not Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just for anyone looking to do something like this, I've figured out a way to accomplish what I'm after. It may not be the best way, but it's working... Now, when a user clicks on a link in my https site and get transferred to an external http site, they'll see the visitor came from my site in their web stats (unless they have javascript disabled).

1. First, this may not apply to any of you, but since I have my global.asax file set to redirect non https entered url's to https, I had to make an exception for a specific folder in that global code, then I put a new aspx page in there to serve as my pass-through page. Let's say the new folder's name is "Link".
2. Then I set my hyperlink to point to that page when clicked and assign some querystring parameters to it so I can pull the necessary information in the non-secure pass-through page. In the code behind I apply it in the Page_Load for the HyperLink with ID "link" like:  **link.NavigateUrl = ResolveUrl("http://www.mywebsitehere.com/Link/l.aspx?id=" + lnkid.Text);**  My links are populated in a datalist, so I added a label inside the datalist ItemTemplate ' Visible="false" /> to get my id for that link and apply it to the hyperlink via the codebehind previously mentioned in bold text. This way I can pull my URL information from the database on the pass-through page. Be sure to set the link target as "_blank", so it pops up in a new window. Otherwise if a user clicks the back button, it'll return them to the pass-through page (instead of back to your page they clicked the link on), which will send them back to the link again and they'll likely get frustrated.
3. Then the rest is accomplished in my non-secure "pass-through" page that I setup in the "/Link" folder. The big problem here was just using a response.redirect didn't attach any referrer information, because it was just pulling it from the https page that the link was initially clicked on. I've read that a click event is required to set the http_referer. The trick I used was to add a button to this pass-through page "l.aspx" and assign the proper link to it in the codebehind to automatically click it with javascript. Then the referrer information is added before the user is transferred to the link's destination. However, If javascript is disabled in the browser, it just uses response.redirect, so the http_referer isn't added in that case, but this will still take care of a majority of the traffic.

.aspx page

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="l.aspx.cs" Inherits="Link_l" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Literal ID="nsliteral" runat="server" />

        <!--set borderwidth to zero and backcolor to white to hide the button. Otherwise it shows for a brief moment during the transfer.-->
        <asp:Button ID="testbtn" runat="server" OnClick="Btn_Click" Visible="true" BorderWidth="0" BackColor="White" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.cs codebehind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Link_l : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string weburl;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    AddMetaContentType();

    //add noscript to literal for users to have javascript disabled.
    nsliteral.Text = "<noscript><meta http-equiv=REFRESH content=0;URL=" + Request.Url + "&js=0></noscript>";


        //read querystring and pull link info from database, then redirect to link destination

        //redirect user to proper destination link that was clicked on in https page
        //created to get around https (secure) site preventing referrer url showing in stats when linking out to http sites for browsers that won't recognize the "content-type" meta tag.

        if (Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() != null)
        {
            SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource();
            ds.ID = "LinkDataSource";
            Page.Controls.Add(ds);
            ds.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionStringNameHere"].ConnectionString;

            ds.SelectCommand = "SELECT ID, LinkURL FROM your_DatabaseTable WHERE ID = @ID";

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ds.SelectParameters.Add("ID", DbType.Int32, Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
            }

            DataView dv;
            dv = (DataView)ds.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            if (dv.Table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                DataRowView dr = dv[0];

                weburl = (string)dr["LinkURL"].ToString();

                if (Request.QueryString["js"] != null)
                {
                    //JavaScript is not detected to be enabled
                    Response.Redirect("http://" + weburl, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    //JavaScript is detected okay. Add javascript to click button with id "testbtn"
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ClickScript", "<script language='javascript'>document.getElementById('" + testbtn.ClientID + "').click();</script>");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
             //this page was visited with no id value in querystring
        }
}

protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://" + weburl, false);
}

private void AddMetaContentType()
{
    //went ahead and added meta tag that will help define referring domain in some browsers
    HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();

    meta.HttpEquiv = "content-type";

    meta.Content = Response.ContentType + "; charset=" + Response.ContentEncoding.HeaderName;

    Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);

}
}
```

Anyway, this is what I did to get it working. If anyone see's any big problems, please let me know. Otherwise, I hope someone will find it helpful.